# Phonegap (iOS) fixed header with input slides down on keyboard show

Tags: javascript, html, css, cordova, phonegap

I have a 'postion: fixed;' header with a search box inside of it. If the page is scrolled all the way to the top, everything works great: [As in this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lA8JR.png)

Unfortunately, if the user scrolls down the page at all, when selecting the search box, the whole header slides down toward the middle of the page: [As in this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dr9nt.png)

How can ensure that the header will stay at the top regardless of if the user is scrolled down the page or not and regardless of if the keyboard is shown or not?

Comment: Try to create an JSFiddle or codepen illustrating the problem

Comment: The problem is only on iOS and only occurs when the native, virtual keyboard displays so a JSFiddle would not showcase the problem, unfortunately.

Comment: is hard to detect the problem, an JSFiddle can help to check if something on the code can lead to the issue. Do you have any CSS transform on the page?